# How to determine which request nginx sends to a proxy and which it serves?

Tags: nginx, logging

I currently have nginx proxying for [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/), but set up to serve static files for the app that Thin is serving instead of proxying the request.

What I'd like to know is how I can check that the rules are set up correctly. Since Thin doesn't log requests, I would need to set up nginx logs in such a way that it shows which requests were served as files and which were passed to Thin. Is this even possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your configuration, it may be easy to achieve. Here is my solution...

```
server {
  server_name domainname.com;
  root /path/to/files;
  # index index.php index.html;

  # logging of all requests in access.log
  access_log /some/path/such/as/var/log/nginx/access.log;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri @thin;
  }

  location @thin {
    # pass the requests to thin
    # proxy_pass http://thin;

    # proxy specific logging in proxy-access.log
    access_log /some/path/such/as/var/log/nginx/proxy-access.log;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i tried to use upstream_addr for host it didnt work

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/678521/nginx-how-to-set-host-header-to-the-server-chosen-load-balancing

Answer (score 3):

create a custom log format that includes `$upstream_response_time` - if your backend serves it you should get a number of milliseconds to get a response, if nginx serves it internally you should get a dash

Answer (score 1):

It's a really dirty hack, but make it so that either Nginx or Thin don't have read permissions to those files. :)
That way you'll be able to figure out which one gets an error, hence reading/serving a file.

Alternatively, you should be able to add a custom header to the config block that serves static files. Then you'll be able to see presence of the header or not.